# How to assign the TField to TcxGridtableViewColumn

Tags: delphi

I am working on one project where I want to assign the `TField` to the `TcxGridTableViewColumn`.
When I am Trying to do this it is Showing Error as `Incompatible type TField with TcxGridTableViewColumn`.

To overcome this I tried to do this by Typecasting But I am Unable to do this too.
In this case it is showing Exception as `Unable to edit Running Database`.

I am not able to trace out the solution.
Can any one tell me the way to do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should change the delphi version to be the one you are using and also keep the Delphi tag. for the question, I don't understand what you are trying to do. A TField is one type of object and a TcxGridTableViewColumn is a different type. What would you like to accomplish at the end of the day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to bind the column of a TcxGrid to a field in a dataset, you need to connect the gridView.DataController.DataSource property to a TDataSource that is link to your dataset. The grid can then either retrieve it's fields and create columns for those fields, or you can create them manually and set the column.DataBinding.Fieldname property to the field.FieldName property.